# NodaTime : Datetime substitute type

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

I have a Datetime property in my application

```
public DateTime OrderUpdated { get; set; }
```

And before storing in the database I do this:

```
OrderUpdated = DateTime.Now;
```

The corresponding field in the sql server database is also of type datetime.

I have heard a lot about NodaTime and wanted to use it. However I am not sure what the replacement NodaTime types should be for my application and what changes do I need to make to my sql server datetime type. All I would like to do is to store the datetime in terms of UTC and NOT the local datetime where the code is running. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you simply do `DateTime.UtcNow`, then?

Comment: As I said I want to start using Nodatime. My application is going to become more complex so I would like to get away with .net datetime.

Comment: Have you read the user guide? http://nodatime.org/userguide/ - if you have specific questions that aren't covered there, I'd be happy to answer those and update the user guide. "What types should I use" is definitely covered though.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Skeet, that was very helpful. Do you recommend using NodaTime types on domain entities when working with ORM's?

Comment: It depends on how easy it is to specify custom conversions. Most ORMs will "know" about `DateTime` values and be able to store those appropriately, and issue queries with them. Again depending on the ORM, you *may* be able to write a property which exposes the Noda Time type and converts to/from `DateTime` internally.

Comment: Thank you.Appreciate your help.